# Library import issue in Intelij Idea and Play Framework

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, slick

I have project that used Play Framework 2.3.4 and Slick 2.1.0. Intelij Idea version is 13.1.4, with installed Scala and Play 2.0 plugins.

When I trying to import database driver

```
import play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple._
```

Idea writes me that this import is incorrect, and they cant resolve it.
But if I run application, they will compiled and executed correctly.

Did someone knows how to fix Idea imports? Because without it, features like auto substitution will not working.

Comment: Usually it's because you have to run sbt update inside idea, once you added the dependency a little green cloud on the right side appears where you can update, or open the sbt plugin from a shortcut and on the left corner there should be the update command.

Comment: I did this before creation of the question. Nope, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution of this problem:

1. Compile play project through terminal
2. In Intelij Idea use "Cache Invalidating" (File->Invalidate caches/Restart->Invalidate and restart)
3. Wait until Idea restarts and indexing project
4. Profit